# Submit add on to Internet Explorer Gallery

Tags: internet-explorer

I am developing a browser extension for Internet Explorer and want to submit it to the Internet Explorer Gallery. Unfortunately there is not a lot of information on how to do it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hi, there is no submission process available at the http://iegallery.com site. I don't think MSFT is offering promotion for any new IE extensions/addons on their site. I host my IE menu and command bar button extensions on GitHub. You can promote Site Search Providers, Accelerators and Pinned sites from your own website. COM toobars and BHO's are a no go. The MSDN forum for IE extension developers is https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/home?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

Comment: Thanks for the info. What do you mean that BHOs are a no go?